# Priority Queue implemented Heap

Tags: java, compiler-errors, heap, priority-queue, comparable

Hi so i am suppose to be making a priority queue implemented Heap in descending order, largest to small, I want to this with exponents. So i fnished my heap and priority queue classes, but now when making my class I get an error saying

```
xponents.java:66: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
public Exponent(int num, int exponent, int x)
```

I'm not sure where im going wrong

```
  public class Exponents implements Comparable<Exponents>
{
   private int num;
   private int exponent;
   private int x;

   public Exponents(int num, int exponent, int x)
   {
      this.num = num;
      this.exponent = exponent;
      this.x = x;
   }
   public int Answer()
   {
      int x = Math.pow(num,exponent);
      return x;
   }

    public String toString()
   {
      String s = ("Exponent: " + exponent + "\n Number: "+ num + "\nYour x is: )" + x);
      return s;
   }
   public int compareTo(Answer e)
   {
      return this.x - o.x;
   }
}
```

Problem was fixed because of a typo and now im getting more errors, im not really sure what i wrote wrong:

```
Exponents.java:83: error: cannot find symbol
   public int compareTo(Answer e)
                    ^
  symbol:   class Answer
  location: class Exponents



Exponents.java:74: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
      int x = Math.pow(num,exponent);


                  ^
Exponents.java:85: error: cannot find symbol
      return this.x - o.x;
                  ^
  symbol:   variable o
  location: class Exponents
3 errors
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo in your constructor. Your class is named `Exponents` but in your constructor, it says `Exponent`. It becomes an invalid method declaration because it is looking for a return data type since the name of the 'constructor' you created is not the same as the name of the class.

Edit:

1. You do not have a class name `Answer`.
2. You cannot implicitly cast double to int. You can use `Math.pow(num,exponent).intValue()`
3. You do not have a variable named `o` within the scope of the method or the class.

Comment: i fixed it but then it gave me even more errors, not sure where i went wrong,

Comment: thanks, i fixed them already but thanks though i got it to work and now i'm working on my main method :D